# Convert rtf to pdf removing the hidden text of rtf file

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, centos, conversion, openoffice

I am using [Ted](http://www.nllgg.nl/Ted) on CentOS 6, for conversion of RTF to PDF documents via shell_exec command from php script like:

shell_exec(rtf2pdf.sh test.rtf test.pdf)

But the issue is that if the RTF file has any hidden data, that is being displayed in the converted PDF file.  I would like to hide (or remove) the hidden data in the converted PDF file. I see Ted has no support for it. I also tried manually removing the blocks that contain '\v' in the RTF file (that implies hidden data) with the php code, but i hope that's not an optimal solution.

Should I go with LibreOffice / OpenOffice with PyodConverter?

**EDIT:**

I switched to LibreOffice 4.2, and it is able to convert the RTF to PDF via the command line, and it does hide the hidden data of RTF in the converted PDF too.